# App crash After core data update on [RKManagedObjectRequestOperation obtainPermanentObjectIDsForInsertedObjects:]

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

Some users are reporting crashes in my app when I checked it from crittercism. It is giving me below stack trace. I have update my core data with new model version( Using light weight migration). I am using Restkit and Magical Records in my app. I didn't get what is the problem ?

```
        >>0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x353a16ba objc_retain + 8
        !   1   Provider 0x00aeb701 __78-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation obtainPermanentObjectIDsForInsertedObjects:]_block_invoke (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:885)
        2   CoreData 0x26c7496b developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 180
        3   libdispatch.dylib 0x35917c6f _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        4   libdispatch.dylib 0x35921559 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 46
        5   CoreData 0x26c74857 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 200
        6   Provider 0x00aeb555 -[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation obtainPermanentObjectIDsForInsertedObjects:] (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:882)
        7   Provider 0x00ae8c67 __79-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation performMappingOnResponseWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke348 (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:645)
        8   Provider 0x00b15961 -[RKResponseMapperOperation willFinish] (RKResponseMapperOperation.m:325)
        9   Provider 0x00b1609d -[RKResponseMapperOperation main] (RKResponseMapperOperation.m:412)
        10  Foundation 0x27b7cb0d -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 766
        11  Foundation 0x27c21d93 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
        12  libdispatch.dylib 0x359224d3 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1460
        13  libdispatch.dylib 0x35921da1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 82
        14  libdispatch.dylib 0x35924491 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 386
        15  libdispatch.dylib 0x359258a3 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x35a99d9d _pthread_wqthread + 666
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x35a99af0 start_wqthread + 6
```

Comment: Run the app with core data thread debugging enabled and see if it crashes and tells you where

Comment: By Adding this flag I am getting multiple " +[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:" violations.

Comment: So now you can look at where - why

Comment: Does each of these violations means it is crashing in production?

Comment: each means it could crash randomly, though it won't necessarily crash all the time at each